# Как плавно повернуть объект до определённого угла unity при нажатии клавиши?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код функции, которая плавно поворачивает объект по оси Y до 90 градусов:

```cs
private void Update() {    
    RotateY();
}

void RotateY() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) {
        float velocity = 10f;
        cube.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
            cube.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime
        );
    }
}
```

Однако при нажатии клавиши объект поворачивается лишь на определённый процент.

А мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии объект сразу плавно повернулся до угла в 90 градусов.